# Pass .toLocaleString() in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I render a price in HTML with Handlebars. I work with Express so I pass .toLocaleString() in a `res.render`. But here I just pass the price in HTML.

```
{{#each results as |auction|}}
    {{#if auction.price_int_eu}}
          <span class="results__container--price">{{auction.price_int_eu}}</span>
    {{else}}
          <span class="results__container--price">Non vendue</span>
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

But how can I use `.toLocalString()` with `auction.price_int_eu` ?

Comment: Doesn't `{{auction.price_int_eu.toLocalString()}}` work?

Comment: Nope it doesn't.

Comment: Could always set it in array before passing to view

Comment: You mean with a Handlebars Helper ?

Comment: That or if all you are using the array for is to render the view loop over array and format that value before passing to view

Comment: Ok I guess I have to figure that out.